# The multi part identifier could not be bound for a hidden column of OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server

This issue still not been resolved, please advise !

I've seen similar cases on SO, but I don't find a solution for my problem.

If I have a query like this, and when I want to use `BCol2` from `table t` ( union of TAB1 and TAB2 ) to validate a condition ( without taking into consideration the first TOP 1 applied in tblB ). I have the following error

the multi part identifier BCol2 could not be bound

```
SELECT tblA.Col, tblB.BCol2, tblC.CCol
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 BCol2 
             FROM ( SELECT BCol2 from TAB1 WHERE (condition) UNION SELECT BCol2 FROM TAB2 WHERE (condition)) t 
             ORDER BY BCol2) tblB
INNER JOIN tblC on tblC.ColNameC = tblA.ColNameA
WHERE
t.BCol2 = (condition);
```

Any idea pls ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (OUTER APPLY is a product specific feature.)

Comment: @jarlh, thank you for your comment. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT tblA.Col, tblB.BCol2, tblC.CCol
FROM tblA
OUTER APPLY 
(
         SELECT TOP 1 t.BCol2 
         FROM 
         ( 
               SELECT BCol2 from TAB1 WHERE (condition) 
               UNION 
               SELECT BCol2 FROM TAB2 WHERE (condition)
        ) t 
         ORDER BY t.BCol2
) tblB
INNER JOIN tblC on tblC.ColNameC = tblA.ColNameA
WHERE tblB.BCol2 = (condition);
```

please try this one

Comment: thank you for your help but I need to use `BCol2` seperately from what happened in tblB. I just need `BCol2` from the `UNION` which is table t and it keep showing the same error message because It couldn't bound.